# java.lang.SecurityException for startActivity URL on some devices

Tags: java, android

I am getting this crash on some devices and I can't figure out why, I can't reproduce it on my devices. This is my code:

```
String url = "https://www.google.com/"; // any URL
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
ResolveInfo result = getPackageManager().resolveActivity(intent, 0);
if (result != null) {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))); // crashes here on some devices
} else {
    showToast(getApplicationContext(), "No application found to handle the link.");
}
```

I am getting this error on some devices, Play Console won't show the devices anymore, so I have no idea which devices this happens on, but it doesn't happen on many:

```
Exception java.lang.SecurityException:
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:1966)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1934)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1884)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity (IActivityManager.java:3619)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity (Instrumentation.java:1669)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4689)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult (Activity.java:4647)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity (Activity.java:5008)
  at android.app.Activity.startActivity (Activity.java:4976)
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem? I don't remember seeing this crash in the past and I didn't change anything in my app since then.

This happens on a few Android versions, from Android 7 to Android 11.

Comment: Crash log isn't clear but isn't there is change for apps targeting android 12 or higher you need to add  android:exported="true" in Launcher activity tag. It does give security exception we don't add it and run-on android 12 or higher.

Comment: That's all I have in the crash log. I forgot to mention, this happens on a few Android versions, from Android 7 to Android 11, looks like no Android 12. I also already have android:exported="true" in launcher activity tag.

Answer (score 2):

If you rewrite your code as:

```java
String url = "https://www.google.com/"; // any URL
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));

try {
    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))); // crashes here on some devices
} catch (Throwable t) {
    showToast(getApplicationContext(), "No application found to handle the link.");
}
```

...now you handle any reason why you cannot start the activity. It also works on Android 11+ where you might need a `<queries>` element in your manifest for that `resolveActivity()` call.

Comment: Thanks! But I'm trying to understand why this happens in the first place and how to handle it properly.

Comment: @eXistenZ: Um, well, what I show *is* "properly". There can be all kinds of reasons why `startActivity()` fails, mostly tied to manufacturers screwing around with things. For example, they might have some sort of "parental controls" mode that blocks activity starts but does not report proper results from `PackageManager`.

Comment: I think you're right, just wanted to make sure that I need to display an error message or launch the link in a different way. By the way, with your code, wouldn't `catch (Exception e)` be sufficient? Thanks!

Comment: @eXistenZ: "wouldn't `catch (Exception e)` be sufficient?" -- probably, but I tend to take the approach of "I really don't want to crash". If for some reason your `startActivity()` call triggers an `OutOfMemoryError`, `Exception` will not cover that. Admittedly, in that case even if you survive this spot, probably you are doomed to crash shortly anyway. But, I don't keep a mental record of what `Error` objects can be thrown in all circumstances, so I tend to use `Throwable` for "catch all the things" in spots like this. That is a personal preference.

Comment: Understood, thanks for clearing that up!